# Twilio IP messaging set up with JS SDK

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm having some serious troubles setting up IPMessaging services with Twilio.

I've set up the backend (PHP) for user authentication. I'm able to generate a Token with the Twillio Library.

I've also set up the user related APIs, in order to create/update/delete users for the Chat Service from the backend. I had to do this with curl however, because the library kept returning fatal errors, even if I downloaded the PHP SDK via composer and simply copy/pasted the docs examples.

I've finally got to the point in which I can create users via the backend, and then create tokens with the `ServiceSId`, user `Identity` and `deviceId`.

On the JS client side it's again impossible to set up the service, as following the Docs results in multiple errors.

I have first included the JS SDK from Twilio CDN (same v. of the docs).

I have then tried to initialize the client as so:

```
var token = gottenFromOurAPI;

var chatClient = new Twilio.Chat.Client(token);
chatClient.initiazlie()
  .then(testchat);

function testchat(){ };
```

(as explained here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/initializing-sdk-clients)

I get this in the console:

```
angular.js:13920 chatClient: t {_events: Object, _maxListeners: undefined, _config: e, _channelsPromise: Promise, _channels: t…}
angular.js:13920 TypeError: chatClient.getChannels is not a function
    at testchat (supportchat.controller.js:33)
    at processQueue (angular.js:16383)
    at angular.js:16399
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17682)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17495)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17790)
    at done (angular.js:11831)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:12033)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11966)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13920(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10467processQueue @ angular.js:16391(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16399$eval @ angular.js:17682$digest @ angular.js:17495$apply @ angular.js:17790done @ angular.js:11831completeRequest @ angular.js:12033requestLoaded @ angular.js:11966
twilio-chat.min.js:246 POST https://cds.twilio.com/v3/Lists 401 (Unauthorized)(anonymous function) @ twilio-chat.min.js:246t @ twilio-chat.min.js:196s @ twilio-chat.min.js:246p.post @ twilio-chat.min.js:246f.post @ twilio-chat.min.js:246value @ twilio-chat.min.js:245value @ twilio-chat.min.js:244(anonymous function) @ twilio-chat.min.js:244
twilio-chat.min.js:150 Chat E: Failed to create session Objectbody: Objectdescription: "Unauthorized"headers: ObjectContent-Type: "application/json"Twilio-Request-Id: "RQb761bc6d95034e23b4ba244e965334d4"__proto__: Objectstatus: 401__proto__: Objectvalue @ twilio-chat.min.js:150(anonymous function) @ twilio-chat.min.js:150
:3000/#/dashboard:1 Uncaught (in promise) Object {status: 401, description: "Unauthorized", headers: Object, body: Object}
:3000/#/dashboard:1 Uncaught (in promise) Objectbody: Objectdescription: "Unauthorized"headers: Objectstatus: 401__proto__: Object
:3000/#/dashboard:1 Uncaught (in promise) Objectbody: Objectdescription: "Unauthorized"headers: Objectstatus: 401__proto__: Object
```

Since I'm having so many troubles simply setting up the thing, any advices on alternative (better) services?

#### EDIT - PHP CODE FOR TOKEN CREATION

```
    $endpointId = $this->idService . ':' . $this->idUser . ':' . $this->idDevice;
    
    // Create access token, which we will serialize and send to the client
    $token = new AccessToken(
            TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
            TWILIO_API_KEY,
            TWILIO_API_SECRET,
            3600,
            $this->idUser
            );
    
    // Grant access to IP Messaging
    $grant = new IpMessagingGrant();
    $grant->setServiceSid($TWILIO_IPM_SERVICE_SID);
    $grant->setEndpointId($endpointId);
    $token->addGrant($grant);
    
    // return serialized token and the user's randomly generated ID
    $tokenArr = [
            'identity' => $this->idUser,
            'token' => $token->toJWT(),
    ];
    
    return $tokenArr;
```

Comment: I'd love to help you get through this and sorry you've had so many problems. Is that JavaScript the only thing you've written or have you implemented more in your `testchat` function?

Comment: @philnash thanks, I've implemented a lot more (starting from `accessmanager` down to getting all users' channels), but since it was not working I have cut out the rest, as I am not even able to simple authenticate the user. Have you any experience with JS SDK? I can't be the only one having this issue/the first to try...

Comment: Oh, hang on, you're getting authorisation errors. Can you post your code which generates the token?

Comment: @philnash Added php code

Comment: Ah, ok you're access token code does look fine. I think I may have reproduced a similar problem and a ticket has been raised. I will add the link to this question to my ticket, however I recommend you email help@twilio.com with this report too so that you can hear back when the issue is resolved. Feel free to drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com too, I'd love to get you up and running on Twilio Chat and I'm sorry for the poor experience you've had so far.

Comment: @philnash is there an update about this error? It looks like I'm doing everything right, but I still have `https://cds.twilio.com/v3/Lists 401 (Unauthorized)` .

Comment: Nope, I've tried everything they suggested (also by additional email support) but still unauthorized. Either it's them or me, but I've focused on something else in the meanwhile

Comment: @ghego1 I've made it work. By some reason one of my credentials wasn't right. I've double checked them, subaccount id was wrong. Please try to do the same.